# RoR: ActiveRecord returns null object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The code below errors out (undefined method `org_id' for nil:NilClass).  When the query runs in my controller, there is no record in the DB that meets the conditions (I made sure of that), but an ActiveRecord object is still returned.

How can I save code/time and ensure that an object isn't returned if the conditions aren't met?  Thanks for your time and assistance,

```
org_role = OrgRole.where("user_id = ? AND role_id = ?", current_user.id, 2)

  if org_role

    logger.debug "***"

    logger.debug org_role[0].org_id  #errors here

    logger.debug "***"

  else

    logger.debug "***"

    logger.debug "NOTHING FOUND"

    logger.debug "***"

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Relation.where returns an array of objects (representing the rows that matched where clause of the underlying SQL statement).

The check `if org_role` should probably be `if org_role.first` or `if not org_role.empty?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows:

```
if org_role.nil? 
....
else
....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if org_role.any?
  logger.debug "FOUND"
  logger.debug org_role.first.org_id
  logger.debug org_role.collect(&:org_id).inspect
else
  logger.debug "NOTHING FOUND"
end
```